# Missing $ inserted although I have $

Tags: math-mode

I get "Missing $ Inserted" when typing in this:

```
Genom att undersöka var kurvan ${f_{A}(x)}$ skär linjen T = 20 ser vi att x ≈ 4,3 då ${f_{A}(x)}$ = 20.\\
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: Is that a unicode approx between `x` and `4,3`? Try substituting for $x\approx 4,3$ and see if it helps.

Comment: There is no missing `$` here. However you should be typing `kurvan $f_{A}(x)$ skär linjen $T=20$ ser vi att $x\approx 4{,}3$ då $f_{A}(x) = 20$.` (And no ``\\``, to end a paragraph use a blank line.)

Comment: @egreg well there is due to the strange inputenc design (sorry for that) that some characters end up automatically being math chars so the \approx as a unicode char triggers mathmode (most likely) ... but of course you are right that it should have been written with several formulas in the first place

Answer (score 4):

The missing `$` is probably caused by `≈`. While it may be convenient to use direct Unicode input, not all symbols are defined, so you may incur in problems.

For instance, there's no definition for `≈` with the `utf8` option for `inputenc`, while there is (as a math symbol) with the `utf8x` option (that I don't recommend).

Type your text as

```
Genom att undersöka var kurvan $f_{A}(x)$ skär linjen $T = 20$
ser vi att $x \approx 4{,}3$ då $f_{A}(x) = 20$.
```

Note that `T=20` is a math formula and that commas used for separating the decimal part must be enclosed in braces (or a package such as `icomma` should be used).

Don't use `\\` to end paragraphs, just leave a blank line in the input.